# Need work around for limitation: abstract class cannot be used for return types

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pimpl-idiom

I have a C++ class whose implementation I wish to hide using a pImpl pointer.  Most of the work is done, and everything's ok EXCEPT for an operator '+=' which returns a object of the same class.  This operator function is required to be in the class.  The problem is that when made into an abstract class, no member functions can return an object of that class, so '+=' isn't allowed.

I am asking for advice on dealing with this limitation.  I'd prefer a way that doesn't require changing the existing code which uses this class. If that way doesn't exist, what else can be done?

Here's a simplified version of the class I wish to make abstract:

```
class AClass 
{
public:
    AClass( int x0, int y0);
    ~AClass(void);
    void operator=(const AClass &A2);
    AClass operator+(const AClass &A2);
    void operator+=(const AClass &A2);
protected;
    int x;
    int y;
};

AClass AClass::operator+(const AClass &A2) { AClass AOut(A2); AOut += A2;  return AOut; }
AClass AClass::operator+=(const AClass &A2) { this->x += A2.x; this->y += A2.y; } 


// 'operator+' is necessary to perform the following operation on AClass objects. i.e.
A = B + C;
// 'operator+=' is necessary to perform the following operation on AClass objects. i.e.
A += B;
```

Comment: I don't actually get why hiding the implementation in a _pimpl_ should require to make your class abstract?

Comment: Doesn't `AClass AOut(A2);` in `operator+` also fail?

Comment: Correct. AClass AOut(A2); will fail also.

Comment: Also, in `operator+()`, `return AOut();` should be `return AOut;`.  In `operator+=()`, `$this` should be `this`, it is missing `return *this;`, and the return type must be `AClass&`.

Comment: "*when made into an abstract class, no member functions can return an object of that class, so '+=' isn't allowed.*" - not true. `operator+=()` is expected to return `AClass&` instead of `AClass`, so it can be used in an abstract class.

Comment: If you have an abstract base, then you intend to have derived classes. If you're "adding" derived classes together, then your implementation of operator+ would probably need to be more complex - after all, how does it determine what derived type the result should be? Furthermore, if you're dealing with derived types, then there will be pointers somewhere along the way. So syntax could end up like `AClass* a = *b + *c;` which seems rather clunky. Are you sure what you're asking us is really what you need in your design?

Comment: Made SOME fixes.  PHP programming has me inserting '$' here and there.  I've left alone the return type of the assignment operator to make the points made in the first answer more suitable to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> EXCEPT for an operator '+=' which returns a object of the same class

`operator+=` (as well as other assignment operators) need to return `AClass&` instead of `AClass`.

See e.g. Scott Meyers *"Effective C++"* **item 10**:

> Have assignment operators return a reference to `*this`

This way you avoid the problem of returning the class by value, and make your code closer to the C++ guidelines.

**P.S.** However `operator+=` does not seem to be the only point. For instance, `operator+` has the same issue, and **should not** return a reference. So you may consider this post as a literal answer to the question, but not as the solution for the problem.

Comment: Yes, `operator+=()` and other assignment operators must return a *reference* to the object that was updated.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I added a comment. Not sure if I should keep the answer or delete it though :).